# Drupal 6 CAS "client" won't login automatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, single-sign-on, cas

I'd like to get three Drupal websites to work together using CAS. So, one of these Drupal websites is using the CAS server module; but, when I go to the other Drupal websites as a CAS "client" I still have to press "Log in" to be logged in.

Is it possible for the CAS "client" to check automatically? So, users won't have to press the "Log in" button if they are already logged in? And, if they aren't they can remain anonymous.

Comment: My initial reaction is no: in order to authenticate via CAS the client app (here, Drupal) needs to redirect the user to CAS. This has to be explicitly requested by Drupal; so letting users remain anonymous will never get them to CAS.

Comment: So, I'm using a second Drupal website as the Central Authentication Service. Currently redirecting to the Drupal CAS will either redirect back, because the user is authenticated, or provide a login page. I would prefer 2 modes in the Drupal CAS module. Mode 1, if the client website just wants to check whether a user has already been authenticated. Mode 2, if the client website is redirecting a user to login.

Comment: I looked into CAS a while back, and I was doubtful whether it supports "checking whether a user has already been authenticated," because IIRC CAS needs the client session & cookies to do its thing. So the app itself can't do it. I'm not positive, though; I found the CAS traffic flow mighty confusing.

Comment: Hmm... this wouldn't be a problem if "checking" was implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: See if this helps https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+Login+Screen

Comment: The link seems to be focused on cases where the client would like to provide its own login screen. Here is more follow-up information about the link: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+CAS+login+screen. My use case would be even simpler. The client could send the user to the CAS server and if the user has not been authenticated, instead of requiring the user to do so. Simply redirect the user back with a message "nope, the user hasn't been authenticated yet".

Comment: Thank you yitznewton, for you support! I was able to get oriented and figure out a solution. Here are some related links that helped: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/gateway, http://downloads.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/1.1.2/docs/api/group__publicAuth.html#gaba62986d4729cb8e9ee3b1ad07f295e7, https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS+examples

Comment: Awesome. We don't use CAS yet but might, so I'll be faving this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this functionality is working in the CAS module, but the "Caching mode" needs to be set to "Disabled". See issue: http://drupal.org/node/1280474

Also, the authentication check only happens the first time the site is accessed (until the browser is closed and re-opened). See issue: http://drupal.org/node/1405448

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It's called "[the Gateway feature](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/gateway)" in CAS.

My confusion was because the Drupal CAS module wasn't working the way I had thought it would. Here is what the client portion of the Drupal CAS module says:

> **[ x ]** Check with the CAS server to see if the user is already logged in?
>
> This implements the Gateway feature of the CAS Protocol.

So, digging through the module code I was able to figure out a solution.

**The Fix:**

The phpCAS function that implements the CAS gateway feature is:

- [phpCAS::checkAuthentication()](http://downloads.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/1.2.2/docs/api/group__publicAuth.html#ga21fd1c2665d2e21c03e6a6dd1860cf4d)

Here is a snippet of code that I plan to use:

```
$is_auth = phpCAS::checkAuthentication(); // Returns TRUE or FALSE
if ($is_auth) {
  phpCAS::forceAuthentication();
}
else {
  // Do nothing until user is ready to authenticate.
}
```

I have a couple options:

- Put this functionality in a separate "glue" module
- Hack the Drupal CAS module to suit my needs
- Try to make improvements, and see if this can be contributed back

(If I'm lucky, I might get to contribute some code back to this module.)

Comment: If you want to use the gateway service the way it is currently defined in the Drupal CAS module, there is one caveat. You have to set the "Caching mode" to "Disabled" for the CAS module to work. (They are planning to fix that, though. http://drupal.org/node/1280474)

Answer (score 0):

As one of the cas module mainainers I'd like to request that this discussion get moved to an issue in the projects issue queue.  This code snippet should do absolutely nothing different, since using "CheckAuthentication" should cause a drupal login.  If you're getting different behavior, we want to know about it and fix it.

Comment: I did. Here is my post: http://drupal.org/node/869926#comment-5464034. And then I was directed here: http://drupal.org/node/1280474. It turns out the Gateway feature would have worked, if I had the "Caching mode" set to "Disabled".